# how to find speedup in parallel algorithm vs serial through amdahl's law?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, parallelism-amdahl

serial pseudocode:

```
npoints = 10000
circle_count = 0

do j = 1,npoints
  generate 2 random numbers between 0 and 1
  xcoordinate = random1
  ycoordinate = random2
  if (xcoordinate, ycoordinate) inside circle
  then circle_count = circle_count + 1
end do

PI = 4.0*circle_count/npoints
```

parallel solution:

```
npoints = 10000
circle_count = 0

p = number of tasks
num = npoints/p

find out if I am MASTER or WORKER 

do j = 1,num 
  generate 2 random numbers between 0 and 1
  xcoordinate = random1
  ycoordinate = random2
  if (xcoordinate, ycoordinate) inside circle
  then circle_count = circle_count + 1
end do

if I am MASTER

  receive from WORKERS their circle_counts
  compute PI (use MASTER and WORKER calculations)

else if I am WORKER

  send to MASTER circle_count

endif
```

I want to find beta for the speed up??
beta=fraction of program that is naturally serial

How can I find beta in it????

Comment: This looks like homework. Amdahl's Law is pretty easy and only requires basic arithmetic. I would suggest you hit the books.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? What is the "beta" you're trying to calculate? Have you attempted a solution at all? Show us where you're having trouble, and maybe we can help. Note also that if `npoints` is not evenly divisible by `p`, you're going to calculate too many points.

Comment: @sleeplessnerd  i want to find scalar and vector quantities in parallel code..??